# Can I use a java policy file to safely run an un-trusted app with sudo

Tags: java, linux, raspberry-pi, minecraft, java-security

I'm running a J2SE application that is somewhat trusted (Minecraft) but will likely contain completely un-trusted (and likely even some hostile) plugins.

I'd like to create a plugin that can access the GPIO pins on the Raspberry PI.

Every solution I've seen requires that such an app be given sudo-superpowers because gpio is accessed through direct memory access.

It looks like the correct solution is to supply a command-line option like this:

```
-Djava.security.policy=java.policy
```

which seems to default you to no permissions (even access to files and high ports), then add the ones your app needs back in with the policy file.

In effect you seem to be giving Java "sudo" powers and then trusting java's security model to only give appropriate powers out to various classes. I'm guessing this makes the app safe to run with sudo--is this correct?

Funny that I've been using Java pretty much daily since 1.0 and never needed this before... You learn something new every day.

Answer (score 1):

[Disclaimer: I'm not very convinced by the Java security model.]

The way I would solve this is to have the code that needs to access the hardware run as a separate privileged *process*, then have your Java application run as an unprivileged process and connect to the privileged process to have it perform certain actions on its behalf.

In the privileged process, you should check with maximum distrust each request whether it is safe to execute. If you are afraid that other unprivileged processes might connect to the daemon too and make it execute commands it shouldn't, you could make its socket owned by a special group and `setgid()` the Java application to that group by a tiny wrapper written in C before it is started.

Unix domain sockets are probably the best choice but if you want to `chroot()` the Java application, a TCP/IP socket might be needed.

Comment: That would have been my first thought as well, but since I'm running on a Raspberry pi and memory is a scarce resource I was trying to avoid spinning up multiple JVMs.  If the security model thing doesn't work, I'll probably try a C app that does just what you are saying, but I'd prefer java.  Do you have any specific problematic experiences with the Java security model?  Still good suggestion, I'll vote it up :)

Comment: My assumption was that the daemon will be written in C so its overhead should be comparatively low. Don't you have to go to C for the hardware access anyway? I don't have any negative experiences I can quote but I think that if an OS-level security mechanism is present, it should be used and mimicking it at the application level is an inferior solution. People more involved with this told me informally that breaking out of JVM constraints is “easy” but I'm not competent to speak about this.

Comment: Hardware access seems to be through /dev/mem and already implemented in java libraries.  Of course it's implemented in C libraries as well--and maybe even as a service of some type but I'd rather stay with Java if this memory protection stuff actually works--less moving parts, simpler build, and I get to learn something new :)